# Google Sheets API update formatting with batch request

Tags: node.js, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to use the code on https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting to update the formatting of a Google Sheet.

What I have tried so far is creating a `resource` object and passing it through the the `sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` function. I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing things, but it does run without error if I pass an empty `requests`.

```
function doUpdate(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

  var resource = {
    spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
    auth: auth,
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    "requests": [
      {
        "repeatCell": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": 0,
            "startRowIndex": 0,
            "endRowIndex": 10,
            "startColumnIndex": 1,
            "endColumnIndex": 2
          },
          "cell": {
            "userEnteredFormat": {
              "numberFormat": {
                "type": "NUMBER",
                "pattern": "#,##0.0000"
              }
            }
          },
          "fields": "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate(resource, SHEET_ID);
}
```

When running this function, I receive the following error:

```
(node:10496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][range][startRowIndex]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][range][startRowIndex]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][range][sheetId]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][range][sheetId]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][cell][userEnteredFormat][numberFormat][type]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][cell][userEnteredFormat][numberFormat][type]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][cell][userEnteredFormat][numberFormat][pattern]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][cell][userEnteredFormat][numberFormat][pattern]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][range][endColumnIndex]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][range][endColumnIndex]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][range][endRowIndex]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][range][endRowIndex]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][fields]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][fields]' could not be found in request message.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "requests[repeatCell][range][startColumnIndex]": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'requests[repeatCell][range][startColumnIndex]' could not be found in request message.
    at Gaxios.<anonymous> (/Users/jimmymaslen/Documents/webscraping/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:73:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/jimmymaslen/Documents/webscraping/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:16:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:10496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am confused by this, as the request object I am sending is copy and pasted from Google's API documentation.

Does anyone know what the proper way to send this kind of a request to Google Sheets API is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `auth` is included in `const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});`. So in this case, `auth` is not required to be used in `resource`.
- `repeatCell` request is used for the batchUpdate method of Sheets API.
- When the batchUpdate method is used, your `resource` is required to be modified.

These points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please confirm whether `SHEET_ID` has already been declared.

```
function doUpdate(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth });

  var resource = {
    spreadsheetId: SHEET_ID,
    resource: {
      requests: [
        {
          repeatCell: {
            range: {
              sheetId: 0,
              startRowIndex: 0,
              endRowIndex: 10,
              startColumnIndex: 1,
              endColumnIndex: 2,
            },
            cell: {
              userEnteredFormat: {
                numberFormat: {
                  type: "NUMBER",
                  pattern: "#,##0.0000",
                },
              },
            },
            fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource);
}
```

- When above script is run, the number format of cells of "B1:B10" in the sheet of sheet ID `0` is modified.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that your `auth` can be used for using the batchUpdate method of Sheets API for the Google Spreadsheet of `SHEET_ID`. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)